# REACT onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave PopUp flickering loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

I'm building a button that shows a PopUp when hovered. To achieve this, I'm using the state "activeToolTip" that turns true "onMouseEnter" / false "onMouseLeave", and in turn renders the PopUp ***({activeToolTip ? ( <>popUp<> : null))***.

However, when hovering the button, the PopUp flickers between the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave.

Can you help me understand the problem?

My code:

```
import { TooltipClose } from "../../../utils/svg";

export default function CustomTooltipsRed() {

    const [activeToolTip, setActiveToolTip] = useState(false);
    let TooltipTimeout;


    const showToolTip = () => {
        TooltipTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            setActiveToolTip(true);
        }, 50);
    };


    const hideToolTip = () => {
        setActiveToolTip(false);
        clearInterval(TooltipTimeout);
    };

    return (

        <div className="flex items-center justify-center ">
            <button
                className="bg-pink-500 text-white font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded shadow mr-1 mb-1 "
                onMouseEnter={() => showToolTip()}
                onMouseLeave={() => hideToolTip()}
            >
                Hover button
            </button>

            {activeToolTip ? (
                <>
                    <div className="justify-center items-center flex fixed inset-0 outline-none focus:outline-none ">
                        <div className="relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-xl">
                            {/*content*/}
                            <div className="border-0 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full bg-[#F43F5E] outline-none">
                                {/*header*/}
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-start p-2 rounded-t">
                                    <div className="mr-2">
                                        <i><TooltipClose /></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3 className="text-base font-semibold text-white">
                                        P1 - Priority Issue
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                {/*body*/}
                                <div className="relative p-6 flex-auto bg-[#1E293B] rounded-b-lg">
                                    <p className="text-[#E2E8F0] leading-relaxed">
                                        We have detected that your tenant has legacy protocols enabled.
                                        Why is this an issue? Legacy protocols can not enforce multi factor
                                        authentication and are considered a security risk.
                                    </p>
                                    <a href="/" className="text-[#E2E8F0] text-xs">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="inset-0 z-40"></div>
                </>
            ) : null}
        </div >
    );
}
```

Comment: If the popup appears under the mouse and isn't a child of the button element, the browser sends a leave event to the button.

Comment: it is always better to use css for mouse hover popup, rather than programatically. React do things in async, so flicking experience is obvious. though we can achieve by react, but would always suggest to work on css, you will have better experience. Browser handles css in optimised way where as React handles things in one go together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [pointer-events-none](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pointer-events) to the tooltip.